# Calculate number of time series in data frame for required hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, time-series

I wanted to calculate the number of series present in the given data.

I need this information for *the time-series* count.

[image: Here is the data]

Here I would like the user to select how to check series.

e.g. Series can be  **Region > Product > Country** (please take this selection for this code also)

Now, series are:

1. Asia > A > India
2. Asia > A > Thailand
3. Asia > B > India
4. Asia > B > Thailand
5. Asia > D > Japan
6. Europe > A > Italy
7. Europe > A > Turkey
8. Europe > B > Italy
9. Asia > A
10. Asia > B
11. Asia > D
12. Europe > A
13. Europe > B
14. Asia
15. Europe
16. World (not included in data frame, so need to do '+1' in code)

As you can see, total of 15 time-series are present (16 including world).

So I need an answer as '16' since there are 16  time-series for selected hierarchy.

I was successfully able to do this by converting CSV to excel and then counting all series. But it is very time consuming if I have large data.

```
deleted
```

Note: Hierarchy used in the above code is **Region > Country > Product**

Is it possible to do this without creating new excel file?

Also, **GroupBy()** is not sufficient in this case.

You can check my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58896556/calulating-number-of-series-in-python-pandas) which uses groupby(), but this question is different than old one.

Here is the numpy array for you:

```
array([['Asia', 'India', 'A', 200],
       ['Asia', 'Thailand', 'A', 150],
       ['Asia', 'India', 'B', 175],
       ['Asia', 'Thailand', 'B', 225],
       ['Asia', 'Japan', 'D', 325],
       ['Europe', 'Italy', 'A', 120],
       ['Europe', 'Turkey', 'A', 130],
       ['Europe', 'Italy', 'B', 160]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, total number of series will be the sum of series with different length. 
Check code below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Construct df from np array
arr = np.array([['Asia', 'India', 'A', 200],
       ['Asia', 'Thailand', 'A', 150],
       ['Asia', 'India', 'B', 175],
       ['Asia', 'Thailand', 'B', 225],
       ['Asia', 'Japan', 'D', 325],
       ['Europe', 'Italy', 'A', 120],
       ['Europe', 'Turkey', 'A', 130],
       ['Europe', 'Italy', 'B', 160]], dtype=object)
title = ['Region', 'Country', 'Product', 'Sales'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = title, data = arr) 
# Remove duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates()

# Count 3 nodes Series plus 'world' like you mentioned in question
count = len(df) + 1 
for i in list(df.groupby('Region')):
    # component before + 1 is counting 2 nodes Series 
    # +1 at the end is counting 1 node Series
    count = count + len(list(i[1].groupby('Product'))) + 1
```

Comment: This possibly what I want. I will test with some data and will let you know in a few hours. Thanks you!